# Setting shell script to utf8

Tags: bash, shell, utf-8, ascii

I want to write to following command line into a shell script:

```
cat text.tsv |
grep -Pvi '.\t.\t.*\bHotels|Гостиница|Готель|Отель|Хотел|ホテル|מלון|فندق|होटल|โรงแรม|숙박|호텔|宾馆|旅店|旅馆|酒店|飯店\b' |
awk '{print $0,"\t","column1"} > Text2.tsv
```

However when I put this into a .sh file all non ascii characters get ommited:

```
cat text.tsv |
grep -Pvi '.\t.\t.*\bHotels|?????????|??????|?????|?????|???|????|????|????|??????|??|??|??|??|??|??|??\b' |
awk '{print $0,"\t","True"} > Text2.tsv
```

How do I set my .sh file into UTF-8? I tried:

```
iconv -c -f ASCII -t UTF-8 Test.sh > Test2.sh
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 22):

Bash takes care of your locale settings.

Check it with `locale`

If not in UTF-8, you do like this:

```
export LANG=C.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 4):

The script itself should be in UTF-8.  You need to make sure your locale and your Bash settings are set up properly (really old versions of Bash would need to be explicitly configured to pass through 8-bit data, etc; but this should be a matter of ancient history on any reasonably modern platform).  Basically, this should Just Work.

There are many things which could be wrong, though.  Is the script file properly in UTF-8?  The file `Test2.sh` almost certainly isn't, and you should have received warnings from `iconv` if the input in `Test.sh` was correctly formatted, so we vaguely speculate that you have used some other encoding in this file, which would explain why things don't work.

Also, your Awk script seems to be missing a closing single quote at the end.

Finally, anything which looks like `grep | awk` can usually be refactored more elegantly into just an Awk script.  Get rid of the [Useless `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) while you're at it.

```
awk 'tolower($0) !~ /.\t.\t.*\<(Hotels|Гостиница|Готель|Отель|Хотел|ホテル|מלון|فندق|होटल|โรงแรม|숙박|호텔|宾馆|旅店|旅馆|酒店|飯店)\>/{
print $0,"\t","column1"}' test.tsv > Text2.tsv
```

I assume your regex was missing a pair of parentheses around the hotel phrases.  Awk doesn't recognize `\b` but `\<` / `\>` means the same thing.

If the intent is to look for these phrases in the third column of a tab-separated text file, use `-F '\t'` and examine `$3` directly.

Comment: Thanks!

So my bash settings are in UTF8 as is my file:

$ file test.sh

Test.sh: UTF8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with no line terminators

Whenever I run your command saved in my Test.sh file $./Test.sh

I get: test.sh: line 1: awk: command not found

SO I suspect that although the .sh file is saved as UTF8 it doesn't read the command line as UTF8

Comment: Sounds like the error message is actually "(UTF-8 BOM)awk: command not found"! Get rid of the BOM.