# Passing UTF-8 characters as arguments while invoking shell script from java

Tags: java, shell, utf-8

I need to invoke shell script from java and pass UTF-8 characters as arguments(Hebrew/arabic language characters).

But the characters are turned into ????? in shell script.

I am using: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to invoke the shell script.

And `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, without which the characters in Java itself turn into `????`

Comment: Can you provide your code and output which you are getting?

Comment: Could it be that you're not passing to your shell process the environment variable `LANG=C.UTF-8`?

Comment: can you please elaborate this: passing to your shell process the environment variable LANG=C.UTF-8

Comment: @HiteshBajaj I'm not certain that I'm in the right path to the solution, but you may want to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28477852/697630)

Comment: Show us the code, and make sure that your console accepts UTF-8.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström: 
How do I make sure my console accepts UTF-8

I am invoking shell script using 

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shellScript.sh","تحذير");`

shellScript.sh:
`echo $1`

output:
?????

Comment: @HiteshBajaj If you can't trust your console to handle UTF-8, instead write to a file and open with an UTF-8 capable file viewer.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Used file to write the param and pass the file name to the shell script.

Comment: @HiteshBajaj That's not exactly what i meant. I meant more for debugging purposes. :) But if it solved your problem to satisfaction, that's great! :)